# Server Send Event Issue on High traffic website

Tags: php

we have high traffic website, 2000 concurrent users  and 250K unique users daily, our Back-End technology is PHP 5.6 ,we are going to implement Service Send Event on our website to get notification number form the server ( in other world  send notification number to Browser ),I've seen some example of implement of SSE in PHP , **as an example**

**ClientSide :**

```
if (!!window.EventSource) 
{
    var source = new EventSource('task.php');

    source.addEventListener('message', function(e) 
    {
        console.log(e.data);
        //Do whatever with e.data
    }, false);
}
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
/**
    EventSource is documented at 
    http://dev.w3.org/html5/eventsource/
*/

//a new content type. make sure apache does not gzip this type, else it would get buffered
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); // recommended to prevent caching of event data.

/**
    Constructs the SSE data format and flushes that data to the client.
*/
function send_message($id, $message, $progress) 
{
    $d = array('message' => $message , 'progress' => $progress);

    echo "id: $id" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "data: " . json_encode($d) . PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;

    //PUSH THE data out by all FORCE POSSIBLE
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}

$serverTime = time();

//LONG RUNNING TASK
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    send_message($serverTime, 'server time: ' . date("h:i:s", time()) , ($i+1)*10); 

    //Hard work!!
    sleep(1);
}

send_message($serverTime, 'TERMINATE');
```

(most of the solution are implement it by A unlimited (or long time) loop and sleep for a short time)**this keep a thread per user live and in high traffic like us I though It could be a big problem**,
What is the good solution to implement **Server Send Event** with **PHP**
 Back-End in High traffic websites?

**Note** : I see this https://github.com/licson0729/libSSE-php but It seems it doesn't handle it with good performance solution.

Comment: Keep a thread alive per user * 2000 concurrent users = might need to rethink your strategy!

Comment: `if(!!window.EventSource)` soo...basically `if(window.EventSource)`

Comment: @Andrew it is just a sample, the question is about SSE performance

Comment: @GordonM yes it's terrible, do have any idea?

Comment: @zhilevan PHP is optimised for the request/response model (fire up a script on an incoming request, generate a response, quit).  This isn't really well suited to jobs that need to keep running and listening to events.  Try building the part of the system that delivers server events in something else.  I'm not talking about rewriting the entire application, just consider other options than PHP

Comment: Also, try to consider supporting more than one user per thread.  1 user = 1 thread is a bad model, no matter what language you're using (I've made that mistake in Java before!)

Comment: @GordonM thank you for good notes, yes of course it will be one of our choices to implement this section with daemon ( service).  but it might there  will be some ways to achieve it without leave the PHP thread in busy waiting( loop )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the good solution to implement Server Send Event with PHP Back-End in High traffic websites?

Easy: use a dedicated server (software) that can handle the load for your SSE connections.

It doesn't have to be written in PHP. For example, I have used Nginx modules that do the job very well, and the PHP backend pushes events to them using curl:

- [Nchan](https://github.com/slact/nchan)
- [Nginx Push Stream](https://github.com/wandenberg/nginx-push-stream-module)

If you want a pure PHP solution, it's possible but you will need to implement a server yourself, and not rely on nginx/apache. Basically you will need an event loop, listening to sockets, http protocol, etc. A framework like [ReactPHP](https://github.com/reactphp/react) should help get you started.

Comment: thanks for attentions, it seems they are good solution for handle web service side, how about the backend,  you said " PHP backend pushes events to them using curl" but how triggers the php event.  let's suppose the backend of this  SSE endpoint just  get some data from database and notify the user. ( suppose  new item generation event is not catch-able) .  what's your idea about create a cronjob to run that endpoint each as example 20 second( or1 min)?

Comment: @zhilevan Imagine you want to notify when new *things* are created. When you create a new *thing* in your backend, you also make a request to your SSE server (nchan/nginx push stream/custom/whatever) which will take care of delivering the notification to the user.

Comment: I understood what you mean and it's good idea, but our problem is that sometimes things not create in our back-end ( let suppose external service insert an item to our db or something like this)

Comment: @zhilevan well then honestly I think this question goes well beyond the scope of SO, because now we are talking about your application architecture. Personally I'd make an API so all the services that want to create a *thing* have to go through the same place, and there I can generate the event. Of course there are plenty other options.

Comment: let me describe a situation , please tell you opinion about it.
we register a SSE on client on example "notificationcounter.php" , and  in that file we count the notification items from mysql an return it as a event stream without no loop in php, what happened? client try to reconnect after recoonect time and code getting run again?